# Running ROS Inside of Pepper

Tags: ros, nao-robot, pepper

we are currently working on Pepper 2.5.10 and ROS Kinetic. We want to run ROS with our own applications inside the robot. We have tried some of the ROS projects with Pepper robot, but all of the applications run in our computer. We are thinking to install and run ROS inside of Pepper, do you think this is a practical way to do or do you have any other suggestion for this task.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can check these links for cross compilation (compile on you pc and send it to Pepper):

- [pepper_ros_compiled](https://github.com/ProtolabSBRE/pepper_ros_compiled)
- [pepper_ros_compilation](https://github.com/ProtolabSBRE/pepper_ros_compilation)

or this one to use gentoo prefix (install useful tools like catkin_make or emerge on the pepper's head so compile directly on the robot) :

- [sbre_robot_ros_gentoo_prefix](https://github.com/ProtolabSBRE/sbre_robot_ros_gentoo_prefix)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The first link was useful for this task. It built the ROS inside the Pepper, then we copied [the project we found](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard) into the *System/ros1_inst/share/*. After that we launched ***rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py*** in Pepper's terminal, but it says it couldn't find any executable file under */home/nao/System/ros1_inst/share/teleop_twist_keyboard* .But python code is executable. Do you have any idea why it is happening? .

Comment: You can't do it like that. If you want to add another package, you need to compile it for Pepper so use the second link. Clone it and before following the readme you need to add the package you want in the file pepper_ros_compilation/repos/pepper_ros1.repos.

Comment: You can use the gentoo prefix link to build directly your catkin workspace on the robot head